# how to copy image of vmware server to another server

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have two servers phisical server running on VM shpere 4.1 with windows server 2003R2. Both server is same spec. I wants to copy the image of both server and restore in another test server due to its a production server and need to live even from the test server. My ques is, how to make a image of the VM and how do i transfer to the tes server?

Answer (score 3):

Just right-click on the VMs in the VSClient application and choose 'clone'.

Answer (score 1):

Are these standalone servers with no shared storage? use [vmkfstools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=900)

If shared storage, you can just clone the machine and add to inventory on the new server.